# CWAC-Camera Take Photo on touch screen

Tags: java, android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I've tried implementing an onClickListener on a CameraFragment, however, it never seems to be called. I am probably missing something quite simple. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public class CWACCameraFragment extends CameraFragment implements OnClickListener {

//...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    takePicture();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"click",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that the onClick event occurs?

Comment: You cannot put a click listener on a fragment. Please show where and how you are calling `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: In onStart I just call getView().setOnClickListener(this); Which is probably comepletely the wrong way to do it – @CommonsWare

Comment: In theory that should work, assuming that `getView()` does not return `null`. By `onStart()`, the fragment's `View` should be ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the demo app, I added the following to `DemoCameraFragment`:

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "got here");
      }
    });
  }
```

Log messages showed up just fine. Hence, AFAICT, your approach works, so perhaps there is some bug in how you wired in the click listener.